# Is it possible to format the url with '/'?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net website. I would like to format my url in the following fashion `http://localhost:51785/login.aspx/office/`. The purpose behind this is, I would like to perform some function only if I get `/office/` in the url, else if url is: (`http://localhost:51785/Test/login.aspx`) than that particular function will not be performed.

When I try to put `/` in the url, the design of the page changes ie. I think the CSS and jquery is not getting applied to the page. Any ideas as to how I should go about it? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know about [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

and you can use this code to solve CSS and jquery (**ResolveUrl**)

```
<script src="<%#ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js")%>" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Where do I have to add this script tag?

Comment: instead of <script src="~/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>